# Is it safe to save search data to a text file?

Tags: php, security, virus, file-put-contents

I am saving search data on website to text file on my disk.

I want to know if it is safe to do that. What if some virus script is saved into the file? is it harmful?

This is the code that I am using to save form data to text file:

```
if(isset($_GET ['search'])) {
    $data = $_GET ['search'];
    $date = date("d/m/y : H:i:s : "); 
    $ret = file_put_contents('mydata.txt', $date.$data.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Comment: Why not use a database?

Comment: I am saving to database also using prepared statement. but i want to save into text file too so that i can delete old entries from database.

Comment: You could export your database-records or back-up your database instead. I'm unsure why you would like to write direct user input on your PC or server into a txt-file. Maybe you could try to "GET" the eicar-virus-test-file.

Comment: Use directory outside webserver path to be sure nobody can open mydata.txt from  web.

Comment: then i will avoid to save user input in txt file on webserver. i will use only database. thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I don't see how a txt file with code should be able to run.

Comment: @vinay It seems that you have been sufficiently convinced to change your program design.  I believe all questions should find some sort of system-recognized resolution.  These resolutions include: Accepted Answer, Question Closure (by Community), or Page Deletion (by OP or Community).  Please do your part to prevent question abandonment, because abandoned pages are information dead-ends for future researchers.

Comment: yes i will keep that in mind.